# PostgreSQL not connecting to Apache via PHP but accessible via command line on MacOS 13 Ventura

Tags: apache, macos-ventura, php-8.2, postgresql-16

On a MacOS 13 Ventura I installed PHP 8.2.10, and PostgreSQL 16 from Postgres.app, and created a database, which I can query via the command line without problems. I also obtain correctly the webpage for the `phpinfo()` function in a webbrowser (Firefox & Safari). However, when I want to query the database via the webbrowser and a PHP script, I get a timeout error: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.". How can I solve this problem?

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php
$host        = "host = 127.0.0.1";
$port        = "port = 5432";
$dbname      = "dbname = DBNAME";
$credentials = "user = USER password = PASS";

$conn = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
if(!$conn) {
  echo "Error : Unable to open database".PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo "Opened database successfully".PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

The modifications to the Apache `httpd.conf` are as follows:

Uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Modified:

```
ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Added:

```
#PHP
PHPIniDir "/usr/local/etc/php/8.2/php.ini"
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so "Vlad Atanasiu Myself"
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by omitting the host and port from the pg_connect() function. So, instead of

```
$conn = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials" );
```

I used

```
$conn = pg_connect( "$dbname $credentials" );
```

I would still wish to know why this problem happened.

**PS:** The behavior described above seems to depend on the configuration. For example, on a MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina, PHP 7.3.29 (pre-installed on the MacOS), and PostgreSQL 15 (from Postgres.app), you need to use `pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials")` to connect to the database with the same code as above.

Comment: Did you try `host = localhost`?

Comment: Yes, and using `127.0.0.1` gives the same result as using `localhost`.

Comment: thank you, i got same situation in Sonoma, it is weird but your solution works